# How to check if email address entered in an input field exists in mailchimp list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

Wondering if anyone can help me. I am designing a wordpress website for a client and I need some help. I have installed Woocommerce 2.1.6 and was wondering how I would write a php script which, when the user goes onto a single-product page, instead of giving the default 'Add to cart' button, it shows a input field and a submit button. I would then like the php script to check if the email entered is in a mailchimp 'members list' that I have made.

If it exists within the list, the add to cart button appears and can continue their purchase. If not, they are shown a message that they are not registered for a membership etc.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You could make a start by looking here. http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/clients.php

Comment: I've found this? But I have no idea where to start http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmemberinfo.func.php

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable way is to use mailchimp's REST api. The method you are looking for is [listMemberInfo](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php). Mailchimp provides a PHP wrapper to the api, you find the download [here](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php). After you installed the wrapper you will need your api key and the list key you find in your account.

Of course your could also curl the api endpoint

```
https://<dc>.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/
```

where you post the api key, list and email data as a json encoded array.

Basically a function to query the api could look like this, as an expample we take `us2` as the appropriate datacenter (you find it after the dash in in your api key):

```
function queryMailChimp($email){
    $url = 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/member-info.json';
    $arguments = json_encode(array('apikey'=>'your_api_key','id'=>'your_list_id','emails'=>array('email'=$email)));
    $contentType ='Content-Type: application/json';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($contentType));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arguments);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array('status' => $status, 'header' => $header, 'response' => json_decode($body, true), 'request'=>array('url'=>$url,'content'=>$contentType,'data'=>$arguments));
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I am fairly new to writing Php, and am at a very basic level.

Comment: You can actually just copy and paste the function above, it should work out of the box, however you must find your data in your MailChimp account. We used this function in production, check the response for the 'success_count' value to see if the email is already registered.

Comment: Ok great, so how would I use this to check if an email address entered in an input field existed in the list

Comment: It depends on your setup, but I assume that you want to use ajax to check the email address. So if the button is clicked you would make an ajax request to the php script with the function above, in jQuery I would use `jQuery.getJSON()`. Let's assume that the email text field value is submitted with this call as `email=me@example.com`, then you would use in your php script `echo queryMailChimp($_GET['email']);` In you js you would then check the returned response object for the success_count.

Comment: so the function would go in my themes function.php?

Comment: have you got an email address we could chat on

Comment: sure nicolas [at] liber.io

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.0, This is located at 
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

where subscriber_hash = The MD5 hash of the lowercase version of the list member’s email address.